# Angular9 index.html not finding main.js and css files

Tags: angular, nginx, asp.net-core-webapi, angular9

I've deployed a project with Asp.Net Core Web Api and Angular9 but transpiled code is unable to load its js and css files. However, index.html is accessible.

My Asp.Net Core Web Api dlls are loading from home/user/www/html and angular is in wwwroot folder which is inside html folder.

I gone through https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1080 where it says to change the base tag but in my case my application is on root folder.
 [image]

Comment: Can you show your startup.cs code or update your code to github so I can take a look at

Comment: Eventually, I sorted it out with nginx configuration. Everything is fine with Startup.cs. Thanks Tony